# how to access database on laptop using api on mobile

Tags: mobile, wifi, powerbuilder

I have developed an application using sql anywhere database as back end and powerbuilder as front end. it is working on my laptop very well and i have also used this app on network server (without internet ) using wifi on another laptop. in which the program is installed on that other laptop and it connects database stored on my laptop .
now i want to develop a mobile app which should connect to my laptop and use database stored on it. It should connect the database using WIFI network.
i have knowledge of powerbuild simple programing, SQL and Visual basic. but i dont know any thing about mobile app developing.
Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too challenging, it sounds like you want the app to connect to a network (or your laptop) database vs. the client machine like any web application and this shouldn't be a challenge other than making sure you've opened up the proper ports for the database in windows firewall AND/OR if you are on the INTERNET you'll probably need to set up port forwarding on your local router so that the database requests to your laptop from the "internet" get forwarded from your router to your local subnet (network).

So for example mySQL uses port 3306 (I think.. memory?) so you'd need a port forward in your router that forwards incoming 3306 requests to your laptop IP address, mac address, or machine name (better to use machine or mac).

HTH